# Fitting a gaussian to data with Matlab

Tags: matlab, gaussian, data-fitting

I want to produce a figure like the following one (found in a paper)
[image]

I think it is done using `histfit`

However, `histfit` doesen't really work with my data. The bars exceed the curve. My data is not really normally distributed but I want all the bins to be inside the curve except some outliers. Is there any way to fit a gaussian and plot it like in the above figure?

**Edit**
This is what `histfit(data)`has given
[image]

I want to fit a gaussian to it and keep some values as ouliers. I need to only use a normal distribution as it is going to be used in a Kalman filter based on the assumption that the data is normally distributed. The fact that is not really normally distributed will certainly affect the performance of the filter but I have to feed it first with the parameters of a normal distribution , i.e mean and std.

Comment: "The bars exceed the curve" - that's expected with a random sample - some values will occur more than expected, others will occur less than expected.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some example data, or at least example code you have tried to fit with, and the figure you get (which you say is wrong). Without additional information it is near impossible to help you properly fit your data.

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: What do you expect that curve to look like? That's the *mathematically* best fitting distribution curve for your data, if you want the *visually* best fitting curve then you will have to redefine "best fitting" in a mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand how a fit works, if your data is kinda gaussian the function will plot the fitted curve based on the values, some bars will be above some below, it all depends on how the least squares are minimized over the entire curve. you can't force the fit to look different, this is the result of the fitting process. If your data is not normally distributed then the goodness of the fit is poor. without having more info or data, this is the best I can answer :)